# How to make a line break in a label in Xib

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a line break to my icon description, and I tried with /n and checking the multiple lines option in the interface builder.

[image]

Aqui es donde saco los datos de mi Icon

[image]

It should be noted that my icon is a CollectionViewCell that is generated inside a tableViewCell:

```
extension MiniAppsShorcuts : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.listAr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AccesosRapidos", for: indexPath) as? AccesosRapidos else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
            cell.labelAR.text = listAr[indexPath.row].name
        cell.fetchImage(urlString: listAr[indexPath.row].urlImage)
            return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
        delegate?.alert()
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set your `cell.labelAR`  [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) to zero and [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620525-linebreakmode) to [byWordWrapping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode/bywordwrapping). The default value is `byTruncatingTail`. That’s why it is truncating your label. Make sure your label and your cell heights are large enough to have multiple lines.

Comment: Resolved

Muchas gracias